# Cannot deploy django app - ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi

Tags: python, django, deployment, wsgi

So basically, I want to deploy django (wagtail) application on hosting in my country. Here's what I have done:

1. I copied files of my project using FTP, to /home/ketohubp/KetoHub.pl.
2. I created and entered venv (`source venv/bin/activate`).
3. I tried to deploy app using following command:

```
    uwsgi --http 127.0.0.1:8054 --chdir /home/ketohubp/KetoHub.pl --wsgi-file /home/ketohubp/KetoHub.pl/wsgi.py --master --processes 1 --workers 1 --threads 1 --daemonize=/home/ketohubp/KetoHub.pl/log.txt
```

4. I checked if django is installed:

```
    (venv) ketohubp@hs7:~$ django-admin version 2.2.8
```

5. I tried killing, and respawning uwsgi process using `fuser -k 8054/tcp`
6. I checked what does log.txt contains:

```
    *** Starting uWSGI 2.0.18 (64bit) on [Mon Dec  9 17:37:19 2019] ***
    compiled with version: 6.3.0 20170516 on 21 November 2019 19:38:29
    os: Linux-4.9.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.144-3.1 (2019-02-19)
    nodename: hs7.linux.pl
    machine: x86_64
    clock source: unix
    pcre jit disabled
    detected number of CPU cores: 8
    current working directory: /home/ketohubp/KetoHub.pl
    detected binary path: /home/ketohubp/venv/bin/uwsgi
    chdir() to /home/ketohubp/KetoHub.pl
    your processes number limit is 256771
    your memory page size is 4096 bytes
    detected max file descriptor number: 1024
    lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
    thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
    uWSGI http bound on 127.0.0.1:8054 fd 4

    uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 127.0.0.1:37743 (port auto-assigned) fd 3
    Python version: 3.5.3 (default, Sep 27 2018, 17:25:39)  [GCC 6.3.0 20170516]
    Python main interpreter initialized at 0x55be3db1eb40
    python threads support enabled
    your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
    your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
    mapped 145840 bytes (142 KB) for 1 cores
    *** Operational MODE: single process ***
    failed to open python file /home/ketohubp/KetoHub.pl/wsgi.py
    unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
    *** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
    *** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
    spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 16988)
    spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 16989, cores: 1)
    spawned uWSGI http 1 (pid: 16990)
```

7. I contacted hosting support to see server errors:

```
    [Wed Dec 04 20:53:06.200086 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 4914:tid 140320264152832] [remote 193.239.126.103:49538] mod_wsgi (pid=4914): Failed to exec Python script file '/home/ketohubp/KetoHub.pl/Wagtail_Django_Static_Blog/wsgi.py'.
    [Wed Dec 04 20:53:06.200171 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 4914:tid 140320264152832] [remote 193.239.126.103:49538] mod_wsgi (pid=4914): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/ketohubp/KetoHub.pl/Wagtail_Django_Static_Blog/wsgi.py'.
    [Wed Dec 04 20:53:06.200187 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 4914:tid 140320264152832] [remote 193.239.126.103:49538] Traceback (most recent call last):
    [Wed Dec 04 20:53:06.200196 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 4914:tid 140320264152832] [remote 193.239.126.103:49538]   File "/home/ketohubp/KetoHub.pl/Wagtail_Django_Static_Blog/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
    [Wed Dec 04 20:53:06.200222 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 4914:tid 140320264152832] [remote 193.239.126.103:49538]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
    [Wed Dec 04 20:53:06.200231 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 4914:tid 140320264152832] [remote 193.239.126.103:49538] ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi
```

8. I contacted hosting again to check config files:

```
     DocumentRoot /home/ketohubp/KetoHub.pl
     WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ketohubp/KetoHub.pl/Wagtail_Django_Static_Blog/wsgi.py
     WSGIDaemonProcess ketohub.pl processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}
     WSGIProcessGroup ketohub.pl

     <directory /home/ketohubp/KetoHub.pl>
       SetHandler wsgi-script
       AllowOverride all
       Require all granted
       Options ExecCGI FollowSymlinks
       <Files wsgi.py>
       Require all granted
       </Files>
     </directory>

     Alias /static/ /home/ketohubp/KetoHub.pl/Wagtail_Django_Static_Blog/static/

     <Directory /home/ketohubp/KetoHub.pl/Wagtail_Django_Static_Blog/static>
      Require all granted
     </Directory>
```

Comment: This is a bit confusing. Are you using uWSGI or mod_wsgi? And how are you activating the virtualenv in production?

Comment: To add to that: Your error trace (and your Apache config) shows you're using mod_wsgi and that isn't working because your virtualenv isn't activated. Read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#using-mod-wsgi-daemon-mode) to see how to correctly set `WSGIDaemonProcess` (you haven't configured `python-path`. And you don't need uwsgi if you use mod_wsgi.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I am not sure, I am beginner in dev-ops like things. But I think I am usnig uwsgi, because I first heard about mod_wsgi right now from you, and I will read about it. I activate virtualenv in production just like provided: source venv/bin/activate.

Comment: @dirkgroten Everything I had done with this app, was done when venv was active   ( (venv) ketohubp@hs7:~$ ). I now know what mod_wsgi is. I read article, thank for your help, Will I have to ask my hosting admin to add those lines to config? Or can I just use "python-path" and "python-home=/path/to/venv" when calling uwsgi command (provided in question). Thank you for your help. (Btw, can you explain me what does WSGIDaemonProcess excatly do? I read it is recomended, and it run django instance in it, but I dont understand what it excatly is. Thank you for your time.)

Comment: You're all sorts of confused. You can't just activate a virtualenv in a shell, close that session, and expect it to somehow carry through to a completely separate process. And for someone who doesn't know what mod_wsgi is, you are using several mod_wsgi directives in your Apache config. Although I must say, if you're using a hosting provider that requires calls to support to see the logs or modify the config, you should find a different one straight away.

Answer (score 0):

I got it, the problem was "--wsgi-file /home/ketohubp/KetoHub.pl/Wagtail_Django_Static_Blog/wsgi.py" incorrect path.